# Question migrated to wrong site

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

My question, which is regarding a specific signal processing algorithm was moved from DSP to Physics. Obviously that's less suitable than Digital Signal Processing - however, 3 people voted to migrate it.

The orginal question is [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/estimating-velocity-from-known-position-and-acceleration?noredirect=1) and the migrated is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/35632/11431).

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

Meantime the question was closed on Physics and remigrated back to DSP. But now the part of answer from Jason is gone (because the edit was made when topic was still at Physics I guess).

Comment: Kalman Filter is a standard signal processing algorithm. Underlying system really is governed by physics but that doesn't mean it's a question about physics.

Comment: Now it got migrated back to DSP but is closed. How to flag this for moderator review?

Comment: I agree with you 100% about it being on-topic for us. I guess we'll have to hash this out on Meta... :)

Comment: Looking forward to it! :) But seriously, part of Jason's answer is also missing (the edit he made); in original topic.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully we can get that straightened out too.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is back here and open, there is nothing you need to do. As for the general on-topicness of questions on Kalman filters, they're absolutely on-topic, no doubt about it.

However, you should pause to think as to why your question might have attracted close votes. See the [first version of your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/revisions/3292/1) that you asked. Now that is hardly a meaningful question! Your next reasonable update came 10 hours later and in the mean time, it attracted close votes because it could not have been answered in its (then) current form.

I can't speak for phonon, but looking at [the version just before migration](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/revisions/3292/4), he must have gotten the impression of it being a physics question where you're trying to model the equations of motion. It seemed that your question was not about the state equations, but rather if you've modeled the physics correctly. So given the existing close votes, he must have migrated to save the question.

In future, I would recommend being more upfront about the topic and describe the problem in clear terms. At present, it looks like streams of thought written down as they came to your mind, but it could be improved by restructuring it by:

- Very briefly mentioning the general topic in a line or two (What is it about?)
- Identifying the problem (Where are you stuck?)
- Showing some effort (What have you done?)
- Adding minimal working example or additional data (Do you have something more to add to this?)

I know you have done all these somewhere in the question, but it's hard to search for them :) Clearly focusing on getting these points across will help us understand what you're asking and also let us know what you need help with.